# Setup:di:compile Error

Tags: magento2

When i compile `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` it generates an error

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\market-place\vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\
Order\Creditmemo\Totals.php on line 17
```

I don't known why the class is not found. The class even exists in this path.

Comment: try to disable custom extension related to sales, and then check.

Comment: Share your directory structure please

Comment: Paste the concrete Magento2 version you are running, and a list of enabled modules (bin/magento module:status). So we get more details to help

Comment: Thank you for all to comment and Answer me. I get my mistake . 
Actually i edit `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals` class namespace by mistake

Answer (score 0):

> **And run this Command in ubantu os**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: pub/static does not have anything to to with PHP